# Multiple iOS app submission on iTunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I need to submit the iOS builds on iTunes around  more than 100 builds.

So what's the best way to submit all the builds quickly?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "100 builds"? What's the point of submitting 100 different builds? Apple will take and publish only the latest

Comment: I need to submit 100 different builds.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Deliver](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/deliver) from fastlane to upload builds to iTunesConnect.

Comment: Thanks Ayush, I'll try it.